# how many people have been frozen in carbonite?

Tags: star-wars

in ROTJ leia tells Han he has "hibernation sickness," however in Empire they are unaware if Han would survive the freezing i guess my question is was carbonite freezing common or.?

Comment: There's also an indication in the novelisation that pre-hyperspace ships used to use carbonite freezing as a form of suspended animation. So the answer is potentially thousands or even millions. It's considered undesirable though, due to the potential for side-effects and death.

Comment: It could also be used to transport livestock so they are not running around the ship. In which case there may be some acceptable failure rate.